# Throw this tag under the [bus]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

The [bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus) seems to be used to describe various concepts, should it be burned?  There are currently 225 questions tagged with this.

**Q1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

A1. It has no description and is used for

1. Questions with [cpu + bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus+cpu) when there is a more appropriate [address-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/address-bus)
2. Questions with [azure + bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus+azure) when there is a more appropriate [azureservicebus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azureservicebus)
3. [IBM-mq / integration bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus+ibm) [ibm-integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-integration-bus)
4. [Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus+matlab) mainly talking about busobject
5. Questions with [usb + bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus+usb) which should just be [usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usb)
6. Questions with [can + bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can+bus) when there is a more appropriate [can-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus)
7. Questions about public transport [bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693385/directing-gps-location-data-to-live-view-on-google-maps), which I've removed

**Q2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

A2. Most of the concepts would be on topic.

**Q3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

A3. More specific tags would be more meaningful

**Q4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

A4. No

Comment: really, no "throw this tag under the..." jokes? Except for Matlab, those all sound like buses to me.

Comment: As long as they are all questions about types of service buses, then the tag sounds good to me.  While it may be a tag that needs context, that doesn't make it bad.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, they are all buses, however can someone be an expert in all of them?   Wouldn't retag them to more specific tags be useful?

Comment: I have no idea. Are you an expert in any of them?

Comment: Or just make them more specific. There is the USB bus, I could easily take this as a school bus (where the wheels go round and round)... Or my horrible public transit around here. :/

Comment: Divided opinions here. 7 votes for, 7 against. :-)

Comment: If we have more specific tags available, then those questions should be cleaned up.

Comment: "and has only 3 followers should it be burned" - a comma may be helpful here.

Comment: This should have burned long time ago, the tag isn't helpful. I was about to post a burninate request but found this one.

Comment: @Lundin Except this never got enough votes to indicate agreement, 10 f or 8 against.  So it remains.

Comment: hmm. Maybe we should burn the `style` tag. Only 20 followers...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that [bus] is too broad to be a useful tag.

While all the types of questions listed, except Matlab, are about some sort of bus (as observed), it's a pretty useless tag to filter something by.

'Show me all the "bus" questions because I'm good at that'... said no-one.

Similarly, 'don't show me questions that have the "bus" tag because I can't deal with them'.  What really?  You want to rule out both USB Bus question and Azure Service Bus questions?

The killer is point 4: does it mean the same thing in all common contexts: No.